# android:mediaplayer error(1, -12)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I call `getCurrentMillis` in android media player it throws `IllegalStateException` and I see the following in the logs:

`E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -12)`

I have checked that the video is being correctly `prepare`d.

It also causes `OnErrorListener.onError` to be called with args `1` and `-12`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found that this was caused by trying to play a video which was only 48px wide. Since I had cropped the video in ffmpeg from a larger one I was able to use a bigger crop. When I increased the width to 64px, the error no longer occurred.

Maybe media player has an undocumented minimum allowed size or maybe the narrower crop was in violation of the H264 spec or something. Hope this helps someone.